# Posso chamar um programa dentro de outro?

Tags: c++, integração, opencv

Quero ligar um programa dentro do outro pois possuo um projeto (main, 7 Classes) em C++/OpenCV que deveria chamar um programa também em C++/integrado com o tesseract, passar e receber um Objeto para que o programa (internamente ele ira fazer um processamento e reconhecimento de caracteres).

Por que não faço tudo em um único programa? Porque o programa em C++/OpenCV é x64 e o C++/Tesseract Win32, não há como realizar uma integração C++/OpenCV2.4.8/Tesseract 3.03 x64 (quando o faço gera um pilha de erros, já tentei de varias formas até no fórum de desenvolvedores mas não obtive exito).

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54259/discussion-on-question-by-ricardo-posso-chamar-um-programa-dentro-de-outro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode chamar com ShellExecute ou WinExec. Você pode salvar os dados do  programa em um arquivo temporário e fazer o segundo programa lê-lo.